# How to put bold text inside a code fence?

Tags: support, code-formatting

I want to make a code fence, and in that code fence, I want **bold** text.

I have tried:

1. `<strong>bold</strong>`
2. `**Bold**`

But they don't work.

Here is what I want to happen:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

def popup(message, title=None):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
    messagebox.showinfo(title, message, parent=root, **`default = "ok"`**)

    root.destroy()

popup('foo')
```

I want the `default = "ok"` part to be in **bold**.

Comment: I go with comments next to the item that I want to draw emphasis on. I'm not entirely sure if Python allows it (probably it does), but I tend to go with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62402768/) - look at the bottom most code block. You have flexibility of how to exactly position things in comments. It can be useful for drawing things, as well like [I did here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60742100/). Just ideas for how you can get by without highlighting - feel free to find other creative uses for code comments.

Answer (score 0):

Place the asterisks before the backticks.

This:

> **`text`**

becomes this:

> **`text`**

Comment: But how to make only "ex" in "text" bold? While the entire "text" is in a code fence?

Comment: @Scratte You can't because then the system cannot differentiate what is code and what is markdown.

Comment: @Scratte Thank you. That is my question. Thanks for the answer, it did help me, but I have that question as well.

Comment: @TheMaker I already understand what you want. You can't specify what code you want bolded because double asterisks is valid code in some programming languages.

Comment: @JonathanRosa But I have seen people do it before! It was years ago, so I can't find which question it was.

Comment: @TheMaker That must've been an error. This article says "Markdown and HTML are ignored within a code block" and code spans as well (https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: Testing `t`**`ex`**`t`..  Sorry, had to try. You're right. It's not working. Just like java.**time** doesn't work.

Comment: @JonathanRosa Except it wasn't an error because you can https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32717