# The best way to format single URLs in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, code-languages

When we put a single URL in a block of code on Stack Overflow, by default everything after `//` is treated as a comment, which doesn't look very good:

```
https://example.com/path1/?param1=A&param2=B#id1
```

This can be improved by using some explicit *language format* before code block e.g. `<!-- language: lang-html -->`, which gives this effect:

```html
https://example.com/path1/?param1=A&param2=B#id1
```

and it's better than the previous one.

But I wonder if there is a formatting (or if could be added some new one) that would highlight some essential characters in the URL or even all of the URL components such as **schema**, **user name**, **host**, **port**, **path**, **query parammeters** and **hash id** along with their constituent characters, such as: `://`, `@`, `:`, `?`, `&`, `=`, `#` and possibly also encoded characters with `%` as well.

Here is a poor visualization of what I mean (unfortunately outside the code block):

> https`://`username`:`password`@`example`.`com`:`80`/`path1`/?`param1`=`AA`&`param2`=`B%20B`#`id1

Of course, it would be great if individual URL elements could be distinguished by different colors.

Comment: I could use this feature, e.g. on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803937/4217744 where it would be nice if the URL parameter were highlighted, because it is mainly about the answer.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398403/how-to-put-bold-text-inside-a-code-fence for how to highlight parts of code; I've edited that answer by way of a demo. Other styling generally gets sanitised out, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62933511/3001761.

Comment: URLs shouldn't have any formatting applied to them. Use `lang-none`.

Comment: @CodyGray // is still treated as the start of a comment (or at least triggers grey text) with lang-none, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That... seems like a bug. There shouldn't be *any* coloring or syntactic detection done for `lang-none`.

Comment: "This can be improved by using some explicit language format before code block e.g. <!-- language: lang-html -->, which gives this effect:" - `<!-- language: <whatever> -->` no longer works after the commonmark migration. If you want to specify code block language, you'll have to use ```lang-none

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just tried it and it doesn't seem to be treated as the start of a comment. Can you provide an example? I've never had any problems with `lang-none`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I wondered if it was because the language comment doesn't work any more as Zoe mentioned, but I've updated this question to a code fence and still you can see the result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the recent [transition to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark), the new recommended way to disable syntax highlighting is the following:

````
```none
http://some-website.here/x/y/z
```
````

Result:

```
http://some-website.here/x/y/z
```

The old, deprecated `<!-- language: xxx -->` mode is still supported, but will be removed in the future.

---

With the above said, there isn't an highlighting theme specifically for what you are asking, since this is not some kind of special pattern that exists in any language. If you want to highlight parts of an URL, you can use HTML elements to do so, like this:

```
<pre>https://<b>username</b>:<i>password</i>@example.com:<i>80</i>/path1/?param1=<b><i>AA</i></b>&amp;param2=B%20B#id1</pre>
```

Result:

```
https://username:password@example.com:80/path1/?param1=AA&param2=B%20B#id1
```

This unfortunately does not support changing the color, but it's something.

Notice the bold "username", italics "password" and bold+italics "AA". Also **notice that** you might need to escape `&` into its relative HTML entity `&amp;`.